# Icons separation and horizontal line behind

Tags: css

I search any problem but without results. Have big problem with separation of icons in inline-block after add css spearation ::after and ::before in the middle icon and with rwd of it.here's my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="icon-box">
            <div class="icon_1"></div>
            <div class="icon_2"></div>
            <div class="icon_3"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon_1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;
  background-image: url("../img/timing_icon.png");
  background-color: #97735e;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.icon_2 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;
  background-image: url("../img/presentation_icon.png");
  background-color: #97735e;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.icon_3 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;
  background-image: url("../img/accurate_icon.png");
  background-color: #97735e;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.icon_2::before,
.icon_2::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #97735e;
  width: 100%;
}
.icon_2::before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.icon_2::after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 200%;
}
```

I think my code is very messy and got to fix.

effect,what I want get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcDp8.png)

Comment: You could better just use afters, no befores. Then, simply on the last child, remove the line.

Comment: There is no point on having `display: inline-block` when your element is floating

Comment: there are some problems with your code. i explained below. let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

first. you have common styles for all the `.icon_1,.icon_2,.icon_3` divs except the `background-image` . so, give a common class `icon` for example, to all those divs, or, if you can't change the HTML , use `.icon_1,.icon_2,.icon_3` instead of `.icon` in my example below. but don't write the same styles 3 times.

second. either use `display:inline-block` either use `float:left` . i chose to use `float:left;` because `inline-block` adds additional whitespaces between elements. ( if you want to use `inline-block` let me know . there are ways to override the whitespaces . )

third. add `margin:0 15px` to `.icon_2` which adds `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `15px`

fourth. add the `pseudo-element`  ( `:before` in my example ) to the div that wraps the three icons ,respectively `.icon-box` . and style it as you want.

i added `z-index:-1` so that the line ( `:before` ) goes under the icons.
added `background:red` to it so you can see that it goes under the icons.

```css
.icon {

  float:left;
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;

  background-color: #97735e;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}
.icon_1 { 
      background-image: url("../img/timing_icon.png");
 }
.icon_2 {
  background-image: url("../img/presentation_icon.png");
    margin:0 15px;
}

.icon_3 {
  background-image: url("../img/accurate_icon.png");
 }
.icon-box { position:relative;width:auto;float:left;}
.icon-box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:1px;
  background:red;
  top:50%;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-box">
            <div class="icon icon_1"></div>
            <div class="icon icon_2"></div>
            <div class="icon icon_3"></div>
 </div>
```